# Why do programmers often use idioms like '40+1' instead of the actual number?

Tags: c, coding-style

I've stumbled across the following code snippet I found:

```
char firstname[40+1];
char lastname[40+1];
```

Why did the person not just use 41 as the array length? And why did he use an odd number like 41 anyway?

I can't present any examples now, but I've seen this pattern a couple of times already and never understood what the point of it was.

Comment: In this case it's likely as a reminder that the array has to store the string terminator `\0`.

Comment: Simple: there is no point.

Comment: The specification says "shall store first name (up to 40 characters)" and the declaration echoes that specification.  It is easier to track the 40 than look for 41 instead.  Especially if the 40 is replaced, as it probably should be, with MAX_FIRSTNAME_LEN (an `enum` or `#define` value).

Comment: Like others said, plus it does not matter, readability is the important thing.  The constants will be folded by the compiler anyway.  I often write 1000 * 1000 instead of 1000000 because it's easier to read and easier to understand.

Comment: @MiroslavFranc with C++14 (C++1y), I believe there's support for digit separators

Answer (score 7):

Same reason that we do things like this:

```
double normal_pdf(double x) {
    return (1.0 / sqrt(2.0 * pi)) * exp(x * x / 2.0);
    // or even...
    return (1.0 / sqrt(8.0 * atan(1.0)) * exp(x * x / 2.0);
}
```

Instead of...

```
double normal_pdf(double x) {
    return 0.3989422804014327 * exp(x * x * 0.5);
}
```

The two versions will produce the same machine code, with a decent optimizing compiler, but the first version is *obviously correct* while the second version could be wrong--or at least it takes longer for a human reader to verify that the code is correct.

I suspect that in the case of `char field[40+1]`, the `+1` is there to hold a NUL terminator, and the field has a maximum length of 40 characters.

Answer (score 5):

Just to remind you or anyone else reading/modifying this code that the actual char array has size of x.  Plus 1 for the null terminator.

In C things go wrong so fast that anything that improves readibility is worth its time.

Answer (score 2):

```
char firstname[40+1];
```

The `40 + 1` is used to make it explicit the array can hold a string of length `40` but with `1` byte reserved for the null terminator. A string of length `N` has a size of `N + 1` bytes (i.e., `sizeof` of the string object is `N + 1`). It is used for documentation purpose.